Stabilze Error in cdk deploy for a typescript cdk for nodejs app for aws beanstalk with launch templates
I am trying to create a typescript cdk for a nodejs app for aws beanstalk with launch templates, not launch configuration and I am getting a stabilization error.
Here is the first error that occurs during cdk deploy in the visual code console:

CdkPipelineEbDemoStack | 5/8 | 12:10:45 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment        | Environment Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment' with identifier 'MyWebAppEnvironment' did not stabilize." RequestToken: 97340eb2-0318-ff99-3203-ba7a07162a05, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized
CdkPipelineEbDemoStack | 5/8 | 12:10:45 PM | CREATE_FAILED | AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
MyWebApp-InstanceProfile MyWebAppInstanceProfile Resource creation cancelled

The error is restated again later on in the same output. Here is the restatement:

CdkPipelineEbDemoStack | 12:10:45 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment        | Environment Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment' with identifier 'MyWebAppEnvironment' did not stabilize." RequestToken: 97340eb2-0318-ff99-3203-ba7a07162a05, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized
CdkPipelineEbDemoStack failed: Error: The stack named CdkPipelineEbDemoStack failed creation,
it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment' with identifier 'MyWebAppEnvironment' did not stabilize." RequestToken: 97340eb2-0318-ff99-3203-ba7a07162a05, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized

Here is my code:
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as s3assets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets';
import * as elasticbeanstalk from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticbeanstalk';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

console.log(__dirname);

export interface EBEnvProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    // Autoscaling group configuration
    minSize?: string;
    maxSize?: string;
    instanceTypes?: string;
    envName?: string;
}

export class EBApplnStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: EBEnvProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // The code that defines your stack goes here
        // Construct an S3 asset Zip from directory up.
        const webAppZipArchive = new s3assets.Asset(this, 'WebAppZip', {
            path: `${__dirname}/../src`,
        });

        // Create a ElasticBeanStalk app.
        const appName = 'MyWebApp';
        const app = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplication(this, 'Application', { applicationName:   appName });

        // Create an app version from the S3 asset defined earlier
        const appVersionProps = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplicationVersion(this, 'AppVersion', {
            applicationName: appName,
            sourceBundle: {
                s3Bucket: webAppZipArchive.s3BucketName,
                s3Key: webAppZipArchive.s3ObjectKey,
            },
        });

        // Make sure that Elastic Beanstalk app exists before creating an app version
        appVersionProps.addDependency(app);

        // Create role and instance profile
        const myRole = new iam.Role(this, `${appName}-aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, {
            assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
        });

        const managedPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier');
        myRole.addManagedPolicy(managedPolicy);

        const myProfileName = `${appName}-InstanceProfile`;

        const instanceProfile = new iam.CfnInstanceProfile(this, myProfileName, {
            instanceProfileName: myProfileName,
            roles: [myRole.roleName],
        });

        // Define the Launch Template
        const launchTemplate = new ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(this, 'LaunchTemplate', {
            launchTemplateData: {
                instanceType: props?.instanceTypes ?? 't3.micro',
                securityGroupIds: ['sg-05c0b4a1432e93642'],
                iamInstanceProfile: {
                    name: instanceProfile.instanceProfileName,
                },
                blockDeviceMappings: [
                    {
                        deviceName: '/dev/xvda',
                        ebs: {
                            volumeType: 'gp3',
                            volumeSize: 10,
                            iops: 3000,
                            throughput: 125,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        });

        // Example of some options which can be configured
        const optionSettingProperties: elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [
      
            // Auto-scaling settings, us-east-2 ohio has t3.micro
            {
                 namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
                optionName: 'RootVolumeType',
                value: 'gp3',
            },
            {
                namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg',
                optionName: 'MinSize',
                value: props?.minSize ?? '1',
            },
            {
                namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg',
                optionName: 'MaxSize',
                value: props?.maxSize ?? '1',
            },
            {
                namespace: 'aws:ec2:instances',
                optionName: 'InstanceTypes',
                value: props?.instanceTypes ?? 't3.micro',
            },
        ];

        const elbEnv = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
            environmentName: props?.envName ?? "MyWebAppEnvironment",
            applicationName: app.applicationName || appName,
            solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v6.4.0 running Node.js 22',
            optionSettings: optionSettingProperties,
            versionLabel: appVersionProps.ref,
        });
    }
}

How do I successfully create a typescript cdk for elastic beanstalk using launch templates and not launch configuration?
I tried updating the code many times with code I found on the internet, but its not working. im continuing to try updating the code.
